# how to implement Select all functionality for ion select?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1
```

Sample html code

```
<ion-label position="floating">Select Day's </ion-label>
<ion-select multiple="true"  [(ngModel)]="day">
    <ion-select-option (select)="selectAll(myselect)" value="SelectAll">Select All</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Monday">Monday</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Thursday">Thursday </ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Friday">Friday </ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Saturday">Saturday</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Sunday">Sunday </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

`(select)` output event of the `ion-select-option` component does not work. Is there any other event for it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Is there an error message?

Comment: replace `(select)` with `(ionChange)` . and watch console log if there is error

Comment: @RyanNerd no error was displayed. the method on that event gave nothing at console.

Comment: @AliGhassan method at (ionChange) gave no response at console. I also tried  (onSelect) (onChange), (change), (select).